# How do I properly use tokens and skip with REG query?

Tags: windows, batch, environment-variables

I am trying to get and set an environment variable for the Steam installation path but I am struggling to understand a couple of things when parsing the value of the path from the registry. I have tried several different methods *(some of which were found here or on Stack Overflow)*. What I'm having the most difficulty with is understanding what `TOKENS` and `SKIP` are/do. Here are some of my attempts:

v1

```
for /f "tokens=3" %%a in (`REG QUERY "HKCU\Software\Valve\Steam" /V SteamPath ^|findstr /ri "REG_SZ"') do echo %%a SET STEAMDIR=%%a
explorer %STEAMDIR%
```

v2

```
for /f "tokens=3" %%a in (`REG QUERY "HKCU\Software\Valve\Steam" /V SteamPath') do SET REG_SZ=%%a
explorer %STEAMDIR%
```

v3

```
FOR /F "skip=3 tokens=3,*" %%A IN (`REG QUERY "HKCU\Software\Valve\Steam" /V SteamPath') do SET "STEAMDIR=%%a
explorer %STEAMDIR%
```

Here is some code that does what I want for the documents folder. I have tested this many times and it works *exactly* as intended. I have attempted multiple versions of this method with the `SteamPath` value but nothing works, due to my lack of understanding of `TOKENS` and `SKIP` I do not know what else needs to be changed to accommodate setting the new variable:

```
FOR /F "USEBACKQ TOKENS=3 SKIP=1" %%I IN (`REG QUERY "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /V Personal`) DO SET DOCUMENTS=%%I
FOR /F "USEBACKQ DELIMS=" %%I in (`ECHO %DOCUMENTS%`) DO SET DOCUMENTS=%%I
```

All of the reading I have gone through says `SKIP` is used for skipping *"lines"*. What do lines mean exactly? Something in the registry? something in the code? As far as I can tell, tokens refers to the amount of tokens used when setting the variable, I.E.: `%%a`. Another factor is that I need to somehow compensate for the path value since it will vary per user and can contain any number of spaces. I mention this because it is my understanding that spaces can change how the value is set with `TOKENS`/`SKIP`. I have already checked the SS64 documentation but have the same problem understanding it:

https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html

Here is the INI format of the registry section I am parsing:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Valve\Steam]
"Language"="english"
"SteamExe"="c:/program files (x86)/Valve/steam/steam.exe"
"SteamPath"="c:/program files (x86)/Valve/steam"
"SuppressAutoRun"=dword:00000000
"Restart"=dword:00000000
"RunningAppID"=dword:00000000
"BigPictureInForeground"=dword:00000000
"AutoLoginUser"="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
"RememberPassword"=dword:00000001
"SourceModInstallPath"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Valve\\Steam\\steamapps\\sourcemods"
"Rate"="30000"
"AlreadyRetriedOfflineMode"=dword:00000000
"DWriteEnable"=dword:00000001
"DPIScaling"=dword:00000001
"StartupMode"=dword:00000000
"Skin"=""
"PseudoUUID"="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
"LastGameNameUsed"="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
"ModInstallPath"="D:\\Games\\Steam Library\\steamapps\\common\\Half-Life"
"GameStatsUpload_portal"=dword:0000001d
"SkinV4"=""
"GameStatsUpload_Ep1"=dword:00000016
"GameStatsUpload_Ep2"=dword:00006630
```

Comment: Can you add the registry sample as reg (ini) format in the question?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know what you mean by _"(ini) format"_ @Biswapriyo...

Comment: If you export the registry from Registry Editor the file will be with a .REG extension. The format of that file uses [INI syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file).

Comment: I can do that, but sensitive information will be redacted with X's.

Comment: Not sure what else to do @somebadhat, Steam is installed and running just fine. I have re-exported the REG file and this is what I get:
`[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Valve\Steam]`
`"SteamPath"="c:/program files (x86)/steam"`

Comment: Right-clicked the `Valve` key and selected `Export` using the built-in registry editor.

Comment: Windows 10 Home Edition x64.

Comment: There are no keys in relation to Valve or Steam in `HKLM\Software`...

Comment: That makes absolutely no sense, that **is** the current path value in my question's registry snippet. I also can't _"correct"_ anything. Doing so would break my installation. The Steam installer chooses which hive/keys it writes. I could change the installation destination but the value will be stored in `HKCU\Software\Valve` as `SteamPath` no matter what I do. It also shouldn't matter where it's stored in the registry as parsing and setting the value should be achievable regardless of what it is with reg query.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 64-bit.

How to use a for loop and a reg query to set a program's installation path to a variable.

Say you want to set the path to your Steam installation to a variable.  Find out where Steam writes it's [registry entries](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=9609-OBMP-2526), find the "SteamPath" entry, copy the keyname that value exist under to the clipboard and build your for loop.

For Windows 10 64-bit the location is `HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Valve\Steam`

cmd:

```
cmd /e /q
for /f "tokens=3*" %a in ('REG QUERY HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Valve\Steam /v SteamPath ^| Find "SteamPath"') do SET STEAMDIR=%a %b
explorer %steamdir%
```

script:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions
for /f "tokens=3*" %%a in ('REG QUERY HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Valve\Steam /v SteamPath ^| Find "SteamPath"') do SET STEAMDIR=%%a %%b
explorer %steamdir%
```

[Find steam games registry entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34090258/find-steam-games-folder)

[robvanderwoude.com/regsearch](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/regsearch.php)

[detecting-a-registry-key-with-a-space-in-the-path at serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/questions/409402/detecting-a-registry-key-with-a-space-in-the-path-from-the-cli-or-bat-file)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't seem to work. Running it and attempting to use the variable with something like explorer it doesn't do anything. Another thing I really need to know is what to do in the event that the path string contains an unknown amount of spaces since it seems spaces effect how you set the variable. The installation path can easily vary per user so I need to compensate for this somehow.

Comment: Explorer just opens my documents folder @somebadhat. I added `explorer "%STEAMDIR%"` to try to utilize the variable.

Comment: unknown amount of spaces won't be a problem. steam set the path value in double quotes.

Comment: Still doing the same thing unfortunately @somebadhat.

Comment: I removed the quotes and it didn't seem to do anything. I have also copy/pasted your updated code verbatim to no avail. I would try making a pseudo `SteamPath` key in the registry since you don't have it installed. I will also update my question with a previous attempt that works with the `Personal` _(Documents)_ user shell folder registry value.

Comment: Yes as I have Steam installed already @somebadhat. I can reference and open it's path with the `%PROGRAMFILES(X86)` variable, the full path is as stated in the registry snippet: `C:/program files (x86)/Valve/Steam`.